# if mysql row A value exist then change row B value to 1 with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

This question probably has been asked. SO my apologies. I couldn't find it using my search queries. Anyhow I'm working on licensing server. The basic idea is email user activation code and link. When the user types activation code into the text field then it compares the code stored in the mysql database and if it matches then change another field from 0 to 1.

Can someone provide me with an example?

Answer (score 2):

1. Somehow you should send data to the server (ajax or regular post/get methods)
2. on server side:
   2.1. First of all sanitize input data. For example, you can use this function (from http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/10-awesome-php-functions-and-snippets):

   function cleanInput($input) {

   $search = array(
       '@]*?>.*?@si',   // Strip out javascript
       '@<[/!]*?[^<>]*?>@si',            // Strip out HTML tags
       '@]*?>.*?@siU',    // Strip style tags properly
       '@@'         // Strip multi-line comments
     );

   ```
   $output = preg_replace($search, '', $input);
   return $output;
   ```

   }

2.2. search code in db:

```
$code = cleanInput($_POST['code']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM `codes` WHERE `code`='.$code.'";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

2.3. check if code was found:

```
if ($result != FALSE AND $result->num_rows>0) { /*code was found , you can do something */ 
$code_field = $result->fetch_object();
$value = 1; // 0 or 1 
$updt_query = "UPDATE `some_tbl` SET `some_field`=".$value." WHERE id=".$code_field->id;
 $mysqli->query($upd_query);
}
```

Comment: Thank's I will try this shortly